# Reversing the order of an ArrayList and merging two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, merge

so what I am trying to do is convert some methods in my Array class from regular Arrays into ArrayLists. However, I have run into two distinct issues. Firstly, while reversing the order of my ArrayList, I have noticed that oddly it prints out say, if I have 6 integers, and I am trying to reverse, it will print out the index locations of the first 3 and the actual integers of the last 3. For example it will print out:  reverse order: 5, 4, 3, 96, 87, 24, In order: false. What I want it to be printing out is 941, 874, 102, 96, 87, 24, In order: false. In regards to the merging of my two array lists, I am not sure if it will merge correctly as I am not sure how to convert this line of code to print out an ArrayList. I used these two lines of code to print out my merged Arrays originally.

```
int merged[] = merge(num3,num4);
print(merged);
```

Here are the methods I am using to reverse the arrayList and the method to merge the two:

```
  /***        <<< CODE NOT COMPLETE >>>
   * reverses the order of the elemets in the array 
   ***/
  public static void reverse(ArrayList <Integer> a)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < a.size()/2; i++)
       {
           int reverseOrder = a.get(i);
           a.set(i, a.size() - 1 - i);
           a.set(a.size() - 1 - i, reverseOrder);
       }
   } 

   /***        <<< CODE NOT COMPLETE >>>
   * merges two sorted arrays into 1 new array, maintains the sorted order 
   ***/
   public static ArrayList <Integer> merge (ArrayList <Integer> a, ArrayList <Integer> b) 
   {
       ArrayList <Integer> merge = new ArrayList <Integer> (a.size() + b.size());
       int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

       while (i < a.size() && j < b.size())
       {
            if (a.get(i) < b.get(j))
            {
                merge.set(k++, a.get(i++));
            }

            else        
            {
                merge.set(k++, b.get(j++));
            }
       }

       while (i < a.size())
       {
           merge.set(k++, a.get(i++));
       }

       while (j < b.size())  
       {
           merge.set(k++, b.get(i++));
       }

       return merge;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `public static void reverse(ArrayList <Integer> a)`, this

```
a.set(i, a.size() - 1 - i); // <-- the index, not the value.
a.set(a.size() - 1 - i, reverseOrder);
```

should be

```
a.set(i, a.get(a.size() - 1 - i)); // <-- the value.
a.set(a.size() - 1 - i, reverseOrder);
```

You also have a typo in your `merge`, where you use `i++` in the final loop. But really, you should prefer the `List` interface. Also, you don't need `k` since the `List` keeps an internal index. You also don't need to explicitly size your `List` (but I did here to be consistent with your code). And, I would store the `size`(s). Like,

```
public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    final int aLen = a.size(), bLen = b.size();
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(aLen + bLen);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < aLen && j < bLen) {
        if (a.get(i) < b.get(j)) {
            al.add(a.get(i++));
        } else {
            al.add(b.get(j++));
        }
    }
    while (i < aLen) {
        al.add(a.get(i++));
    }
    while (j < b.size()) {
        al.add(b.get(j++));
    }
    return al;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now how would I change that line of code in my main that should be printing my two merged methods?

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> merged = merge(num3,num4);`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried that before but I guess I typed it incorrectly. That allowed me to compile it but I got an indexOutOfBoundsException error when I tried to run it. It highlighted the merge.set(k++, a.get(i++));
in my merge method.

Comment: @CrypticZero Your merge has a typo in the last loop `while (j < b.size())`, you're looping with `j` but using `i`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wouldn't have seen that!